# Ensure matplotlib colorbar looks the same across multiple figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, colorbar

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

def make_Z(X,Y, offset=0.):
    return np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y) + offset

class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y), np.isnan(value))

################################################################################


x,y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100), np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = make_Z(X,Y, offset=0.8)#; print(Z.shape)
tens = np.logspace(0., 3.0, num=4); print(tens)
Zs = [Z/i for i in tens]#; print(len(Zs))
min_Z = np.min(Zs)
max_Z = np.max(Zs)
norm = MidpointNormalize(vmin=min_Z, vmax=max_Z, midpoint=0.)
for Z in Zs:
    print("min, max: %f, %f"%(np.min(Z), np.max(Z)))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Z_plot = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels=100, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', vmin=min_Z, vmax=max_Z)
    plt.colorbar(Z_plot, ax=ax)
    plt.show()
    print("-"*70)
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Explanation: I make a Z value based on X and Y coordinates, then divide the Z value in each figure by powers of ten (10<sup>0</sup>, 10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>2</sup>, 10<sup>3</sup>), hence the plots becoming weaker and weaker further down.

Basically, everything is as expected. However, I would like the same colourbar to be applied to all figures. At the moment it looks like the same colormap is applied (which it should be), but I want the full "blue-on-bottom-red-above"- colorbar in all figures, even those that appear all white in colour. I am somewhat confident that I tried out all the arguments to `contourf` and `colorbar`, including the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments, but can not get the full range colorbar to be shown on all figures. Any hints?

EDIT:

I had the idea to maybe adjust the `ylim` property of the colorbar, since it is after all just a regular axis. Defining the colorbar as `cbar` and then doing `cbar.ax.set_ylim(min_Z, max_Z)` results in gibberish, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

I don't know if this is acceptable for you, but you can replace `contourf` with `imshow`:

```
Z_plot = ax.imshow(Z, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', vmin=min_Z, vmax=max_Z, interpolation = 'bilinear')
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Option 2

[**`matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) is linked to the mappable you pass it as the first argument. A trick can be to pass to `colorbar` the non scaled `contour`.
Try if this code fit for you:

```
for Z, ten in zip(Zs, tens):
    print("min, max: %f, %f"%(np.min(Z), np.max(Z)))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.colorbar(ax.contourf(X,Y,Z*ten, levels=100, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', vmin=min_Z, vmax=max_Z), ax=ax)
    Z_plot = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels = 100, norm = norm, cmap = 'seismic', vmin = min_Z, vmax = max_Z)
    plt.show()
    print("-"*70)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Option 3

The same concept of above but this time I set up the mappable to pass to `colorbar` in a more clean way.

```
for Z in Zs:
    print("min, max: %f, %f"%(np.min(Z), np.max(Z)))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Z_plot = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels = 100, norm = norm, cmap = 'seismic', vmin = min_Z, vmax = max_Z)
    m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = cm.seismic, norm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin = np.min(Z), vcenter = 0, vmax = np.max(Z)))
    m.set_array(Z)
    m.set_clim(np.min(Z), np.max(Z))
    cbar = plt.colorbar(m, boundaries = np.linspace(np.min(Z), np.max(Z), 100))
    ticks = np.append(0, np.linspace(np.min(Z), np.max(Z), 9))
    ticks.sort()
    cbar.set_ticks(ticks)
    plt.show()
    print("-"*70)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of `imshow` but stayed away because I need (not necessarily linear) axes labels. Notice how your x- and y axis labels are different from my plots. In this example it works by just setting `extent=[np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)]` inside `imshow`, but what about non-linear or non-evenly spaced x and y axis... I don't think this can be done with `imshow`. In my actual problem I have the X and Y grids given, hence why I used `contourf`.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer by using a little trick, let me know if it fits for you

Comment: Thank you for your further input! Your second code-block is nice because it preserves the asymmetric bi-linearity of the colorbar. However I think it only works because we know that Z\*tens is always the largest of the plots. In my real data I'd have no idea what to use instead oz Z\*tens, because I don't know which of the plots will turn out to contain the largest values, what ever that even means. It could be that the max value is in one dataset, while the min value is in some other dataset.
Your third code block works if I want to live without the asymmetric, bilinear colormap only.

Comment: I have updated my answer again, regarding **Option 3**. I edited the code in order to make min and max value indipendent from `ten` factor. Moreover I applied a norm to the colorbar, so now it preserves asymmetric bi-linearity. I added some ticks, feel free to customize them. Let me know if it works now

Comment: Once again, thanks for your input. Life got in the way. My biggest problem with the current state of block 3 is that the range changes. max value in the first plot is 2.796, in the last plot its 0.002796, meaning that now still the same shades of colors correspond to different values across the plots.  I fixed this by replacing np.min(Z) with min_Z everywhere, and same for np.max(z) to max_Z to apply the global max and min values in all plots. Also, I don't see why a different norm should be used either. I got it working anyways, so I'll accept your answer and make my final code a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is wholly thanks to Zephyr's answer above, which I accepted for the third code block, which I have adapted below to be used both in the MWE I supplied as well as my actual code:

```
x,y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100), np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = make_Z(X,Y, offset=0.8)#; print(Z.shape)
tens = np.logspace(0., 3.0, num=4); print(tens)
Zs = [Z/i for i in tens]#; print(len(Zs))
min_Z = np.min(Zs)
max_Z = np.max(Zs)

for Z in Zs:
    print("min, max: %f, %f"%(np.min(Z), np.max(Z)))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Z_plot = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels=100, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', vmin=min_Z, vmax=max_Z)
    m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = 'seismic', norm = norm)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(m, boundaries = np.linspace(min_Z, max_Z, 100))
    plt.show()
    print("-"*70)
```

Differences to Zephyr's answer:

- the only part I took over from his answer is the the line containing `ScalarMappable`, in which I have set the norm to be the same as the one used in `contourf`
- verything regarding tickmarks I have eliminated because for me the automatic tickmarks sufficed.
- the `set_array` and `set_clim` functions I have eliminated because they did not change anything for me, and frankly, I don't know what they are good for.